# I can't assign a rect transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I'm having trouble assigning a rect transform on Unity and I can't understand why!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(PlayerControler))]    
public class PlayerUI : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    RectTransform ThrusterFuelFill;

    [SerializeField]
    GameObject PlayerUIOnInspector;
    public GameObject playerUIInstance;


    private PlayerControler controller;

    public void setControler (PlayerControler _controler)
    {
        controller = _controler;
    }


    void Start()
    {
        playerUIInstance = Instantiate(PlayerUIOnInspector);
        playerUIInstance.name = PlayerUIOnInspector.name;

        PlayerUI ui = playerUIInstance.GetComponent<PlayerUI>();
        if (ui == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("No PlayerUI componrnt on playerUI prefab.");
            ui.setControler(GetComponent<PlayerControler>());        
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        setFuelAmount(controller.getThrusterFuelAmount());
    }

    void setFuelAmount(float _amount)
    {
        ThrusterFuelFill.localScale = new Vector3(1f, _amount, 1f);
    }
}
```

I have a rect transform on my ThrusterFuelFill it is a rectangle, a UI but it doesn't let me define it.

Here I have an image, I click on the circle that lets you have some assign options but it there is't a single thing.

[image]

Comment: What does “having trouble” mean? Are you getting an error? Tell us the error message.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: By having trouble I mean when I drag it and Unity won't let me define it, now I'm trying to do it by code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just drag and drop it in the editor here to assign a rect transform:

[image]

Where is says 'None (Rect Transform)' drag any Game Object from your hierarchy that has a rect transform into that box.

You can also do something like:

```
RectTransform rectTransform = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("RectTransform");

gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerUI>().thrusterFuelFill = rectTransform;
```

Comment: No worries, if this answered you question feel free to mark as correct and upvote :)